# What classloader to use with Parcel.readHashMap?

Tags: java, android, generics, classloader, parcelable

I'm using the following code to read a map of type `HashMap<String, String`> from a Parcel:

```
in.readHashMap(HashMap.class.getClassLoader());
```

This seems to work just fine, but I get a warning:

```
Type safety: The expression of type HashMap needs unchecked conversion to conform to Map<String,String>
```

Is there a "right" way to do this, use a different class loader? Or should I just go with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked"`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Android developer documentation for `Parcel.readHashMap()` says:

> Please use `readBundle(ClassLoader)` instead (whose data must have
>   been written with `writeBundle(Bundle)`.

So maybe you should be using `readBundle()` and `writeBundle()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Although it is strictly speaking not the answer to the above question, it solved my problem.

Here's what I did:

When writing to the parcel:
`  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();`   
`  bundle.putSerializable("map", myMap);`
`  dest.writeBundle(bundle);`

When reading again from the parcel:
`  Bundle bundle = in.readBundle();`
`  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`
`  HashMap<String, String> myMap = (HashMap<String, `String>)bundle.getSerializable("map");`
  this.myMap = myMap;`

Comment: OK, I wanted to format that better, but it's just not working for me. Sorry!

Comment: use readBundle(classLoader) if your hashmap has parcelable objects.